# losetup Find in Parallel / Concurrency

Tags: make, parallel-processing, loopback, makefile

I'm writing a makefile that at some point builds image files.  I'm using `losetup -f` in the file to find a free loop device when building out each image.  Since the images are independent of each other, I'd like to be able to `make -j` in parallel.  Unfortunately, when I do this, `losetup -f` returns the same device to all images since the command is executed at nearly the same time for each image.  Does anyone know of a way I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem as you and found the following bug report in the chromium bug tracker that also describes how to fix it: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=201150

Basically it's sufficient to not just print the next free device but also use it and just print the name so it can be deleted afterwards.

From `losetup(8)`:

```
-f, --find
    find the first  unused  loop  device.  If  a  file  argument  is present,
    use this device. Otherwise, print its name

--show
    print device name if the -f  option  and  a  file  argument  are present.
```

This means that `losetup -f --show /foo/bar` will print `/dev/loop1`, for example, and also associates the loop the device with the file `/foo/bar`.